# is there a possibility to keep adding element in my list after using one list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation, list-comprehension

I am new in python and I am tryin to figure out how really works a list comprehension.

I know that if a have something like this...

```
myList = [n**3 for n in range(1,11)]
```

my output will be the cubes of 1 to 10. the translation of this list comprehension will be

```
for n in range(1,11):
    myList.append(n**3)
```

my problem comes when I want to add the cubes of 11 to 20 in the same list, I know that I can do this with a loop like in the past code.

```
for n in range(11,21):
    myList.append(n**3)
```

but I don't want to do that loop, I want to add these new elements in my list with another list comprehension

so is there a posibbility to keep adding elements in a list using another list comprehension?

Something like `mylist = mylist + anotherlist ?`

I don't want to use something like

```
myList = [n**3 for n in range(1,21)]
```

because it will take more and more time if I want to keep adding more items

I also try

```
myList = [n**3 for n in range(1,11)]
then
myList = [n**3 for n in range(11,21)]
```

but it does not work
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like shown below,

```
>>> mylist = [n**3 for n in range(1,11)]
>>> mylist += [n**3 for n in range(11,20)] # to update in-place use '+='.
```

---

**Output:**

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000, 1331, 1728, 2197, 2744, 3375, 4096, 4913, 5832, 6859]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `extend` method of list:

```
lst = [n**3 for n in range(1,11)]
lst.extend(n**3 for n in range(11,20))
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000, 1331, 1728, 2197, 2744, 3375, 4096, 4913, 5832, 6859]
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that sintaxis.

Answer (score -1):

This command will help you:

```
mylist.extend(anotherlist)
```